# Single Regex to extract a/b/c from a/b/c/d:Z1234 and a/b/c from a/b/c:Y5678

Tags: regex

I have data apple/banana/orange/cherries:Z1234 and
avocado/cantaloupe/watermelon:Y5678

How to put single regex that can get apple/banana/orange and avocado/cantaloupe/watermelon ?

If I put `r'(.+?/.+?/.+?):.*`  I get avocado/cantaloupe/watermelon but I will get apple/banana/orange/cherries (the goal is supposed to be only apple/banana/orange)

If I put `r'(.+?/.+?/.+?)/.*` I get apple/banana/orange but I will get avocado/cantaloupe/watermelon:Y5678 (the goal is supposed to be only avocado/cantaloupe/watermelon)

How can I solve it with single regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```php
[^/:\s]+(?:/[^/:\s]+){2}
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/QR1y1N/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^/:\s]+                 any character except: '/', ':', whitespace
                           (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/:\s]+                 any character except: '/', ':',
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! how if I want to get only the c , watermelon and orange from data above?

Comment: @Allentine With `[^/:\s]+(?:/([^/:\s]+)){2}`, see [proof](https://regex101.com/r/QR1y1N/3), get the capture value.

Comment: @Allentine Another expression: `[^/:\s]+/[^/:\s]+/\K[^/:\s]+`. See [this proof](https://regex101.com/r/QR1y1N/4).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for parts that don't contain slashes or colons, so `[^/:]+/[^/:]+/[^/:]+`.